# Confusion regarding plot of p-value as function of MLE value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, p-value, uniform-distribution

I am trying to answer the following question:

[image]

**My work:**

(a) The power function $\beta \colon \Theta \to [0, 1]$ given by $\theta \mapsto \beta(\theta)$ is the probability of rejecting $H_0$, as a function of $\theta$. Since we reject when $T_n > c$, $\beta(\theta) = P(T_n > c)$. If $F_{T_n}(c)$ is the distribution function of the random variable $T_n$, then $\beta(\theta) = 1 - F_{T_n}(c)$.

It was determined earlier that $F_{T_n}(c) = \big(\frac{c}{\theta}\big)^n$. Therefore, we can conclude that

\begin{align*}
\beta(\theta) &= 1 - \Big(\frac{c}{\theta}\Big)^n
\end{align*}

for $\theta \in \Theta = (0, \infty)$. (Because $\beta(\theta)$ is a probability, we must have $0 \leq c \leq \theta$.)

(b) In this case the level is the probability of rejecting $H_0$ given that $H_0$ is true. Given that we reject for $T_n > c$, we can plug $\theta = 1$ into the above formula, set it equal to 0.05 and solve for $c$.

\begin{align*}
1 - \Big(\frac{c}{1}\Big)^n &= 0.05\\
\Rightarrow c &= 0.95^{1/n}.
\end{align*}

(c) In this case the p-value is the probability of the result observed, or a more extreme one (assuming $H_0$ to be true). If we let $t_n$ be the observed sample maximum while $T_n$ stands for the sample maximum as a random variable, then the p-value can be written

\begin{align*}
\text p &= P(T_n > t_n)\\
&= 1 - \Big(\frac{t_n}{1}\Big)^n\\
&= 1 - t_n^n.
\end{align*}

[image]

**Request:**

I would appreciate a check of my work. I think it's mostly correct, but I am concerned about (c). On the one hand, I feel like algebraically I've derived the correct expression for the p-value. On the other hand, p-values are probabilities, and what I've got is definitely not a probability in the right side of the graph.

How do I rectify this? Is the question poorly formed or am I misunderstanding something?

**Edit:**

```
n = 20
domain = seq(0.9, 1.1, 0.0001)
#range = rep(0, 2001)
range = 1 - domain^n

plot(domain, range, main="Plot of p-value as a function of test statistic\n (sample maximum)", xlab="(Portion of) range of sample maximum values", ylab="p-value (Probability that sample maximum is this large, or larger")
```

**Edit 2:**

Plot has been fixed (I think).

[image]

Comment: When $T_n\gt 1,$ what does that tell you about the possibility $\theta=1$??

Comment: @whuber $\theta = 1$ is impossible. So I guess I just need a horizontal line at zero for the right part of the graph. Thanks.

Comment: Is the y-axis actually the log of the p-value or something?

Comment: @AdamO I've added my R code to the question.

Comment: The failure of your analysis to capture this basic conclusion indicates something fundamental is wrong with it.  One problem occurs where you write "it was determined earlier that..."

Comment: @whuber You mean I was sloppy in that the formula I gave for the distribution function is only valid for $0 \leq c \leq \theta$? I'll cop to that. Anyway, I think I've fixed the plot (see edit). I also have to be more careful about how I've defined a couple functions in my answer.

Comment: Very good.  Although these comments might seem like nit-picking, they are motivated by having seen many other questions of the same sort where people obtained incorrect answers by forgetting to limit the domains of functions explicitly.